# The role of equals in Java's HashMap

Tags: java, data-structures, null, hashmap

I have a question about `HashMap` performance concerning the use of `equals`.  When I put the null-check first, as shown here:

```
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    // object must be Test at this point
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It would be a little bit faster that if I didn't.

So, to create the `HashMap` - I just wonder - what kinds of element compared to the elements in the `HashMap`.  When I put, insert or get, I never insert any `null` objects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I would seriously not worry about the cost of a single if statement - that's a micro-optimization, and unless you have documented proof that it's the bottleneck in your program you should absolutely not worry about it.  Almost universally, slowdown in programs is due to larger-scale inefficiencies and not individual if statements.

With that said - objects stored in a `HashMap` can be compared however the `HashMap` wants to compare them.  This is typically done during insertions, deletions, and lookups so that the `HashMap` knows whether two objects are equal, but it could be done during a rehash (as objects are redistributed through the `HashMap`) as well.  The implementation might even try comparing your object against `null` and then doing some sort of crazy aggressive caching or coalescing scheme in order to improve memory usage.  You really can't assume much, since part of the contract of the `HashMap` is that `equals` must work for your objects.

Moreover, if you don't support `null` in `equals`, then you are [breaking the contract for `equals` as specified in `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), which explicitly mentions that passing in `null` should return `false`.  As mentioned before, this is almost certainly a Very Bad Idea unless you have verifiable data showing that it's a bottleneck.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

A null check which is correctly branch-predicted is virtually free on most modern CPUs. Seriously, you shouldn't worry about it.

Usually though in this kind of situation I'd put an `instanceof` check first, which makes the null check unnecessary:

```
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof MyObject) {
        // do comparison
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need an explicit null check: the `else` clause handles this in the same way that it returns false for anything else that isn't a valid `MyObject` instance..